# Phonegap-Pushplugin: Handling click event on notification in iOS

Tags: ios, cordova, ionic2, phonegap-pushplugin

Expected behavior:
Trigger an event after clicking on the notification.
Actual behavior:

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
```

is getting triggered
as soon as the notification arrives when the app is in the foreground.
  Client side code is as below:

```
const options: PushOptions = {
ios: {
alert: 'true',
badge: true,
sound: 'false'
},

};

const pushObject: PushObject = this.push.init(options);

pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => console.log('Received a notification', notification));

pushObject.on('registration').subscribe((registration: any) => console.log('Device registered', registration));

pushObject.on('error').subscribe(error => console.error('Error with Push plugin', error));
```

Server side payload example:

```
{
    "aps": {
        "alert": "Testing.. (15)",
        "badge": 1,
        "sound": "default",
        "content-available": 1
    }
}
```

**Explanation of problem:** When the app is in foreground as soon as the notification is received

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
```

The method is getting invoked. It is not waiting for the user to click the notification.In my app, I will navigate to a certain page depending on the payload data in the notification.

Now because of this immediate triggering of the function, though the user is in middle of some page he will be immediately redirected to some page after receiving notification.

I want user to click on the notification and only after that

```
pushObject.on('notification').subscribe((notification: any) => {
```

method should be triggered. Thanks in advance.

Comment: It looks like it is expected behavior of the plugin itself https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#overview

Comment: But if the user has opened some page in app and notification is received, then he will be immediately redirected to some other page. So I need to control immediate triggering of function. Is there any way to do so?

Answer (score 0):

you can check the .additionalData.foreground property on the notification payload and only trigger the in-app behaviour if the value is false.  Your app will be brought to the foreground when the user clicks on the notification. This property is about whether the app was in the foreground when the notification was received on the device.

The ui notification itself (in the system notification tray) will be suppressed if your app is in the foreground when the notification is received on your device (in most cases - there are ways for you to force the display of the notfication when your app is in the foreground, but that's a different topic).

If this property is false when your app receives the notification it means your app was in the background when the notification was received on the device. This is the case for when the user clicked on the notification to launch or activate your app, which I think is the 'ordinary' case.

The above doesn't cover all the cases; more details on the exact behaviour can be found here https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push/blob/master/docs/PAYLOAD.md#push-message-arrives-with-app-in-foreground

Unfortunately there is one case that isn't handled well in IOS 11, which is: if your app is in the foreground, but the device is asleep/off when the notifications are received.  On waking the device your app is still in the foreground. The user pulls down the notification list and clicks on the 'old' notification.  In this case the additionalData.foreground property will be true.

In IOS 10 and earlier this foreground property was set to false in that last case, which meant that you could rely on it to differentiate between notifications that were clicked on or not.

I'm not sure (yet) how to differentiate the cases (how to know if the user actually clicked on the notification).

Comment: I wound up using a hack: checking the delivery time of the notification - if .foreground is true, but now() - delivery time is > than some reasonable amount (1minute?) we can presume that the user clicked on the notification.  It's not perfect, but handled the common cases.  I really don't understand why mobile push notifications APIs don't give us a simple notificationClicked event!